# Pandas: How to unstack a series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas (and programming in general) for the first time and I could really use some help. From the data, I managed to create a variable `x` of type `pandas.core.series.Series` using `value_counts` that looks like this:

```
week        
0     SanDOW    20
      SanPCF    18
      SanSOT    10
      SanMSS     7
      SanPEN     2
...
52    SanCOL    2
      SanOCN    2
      SanSOT    2
      SanKER    1
      SanLAJ    1
      SanRNC    1
      SanCAR    1
53    SanDOW    1
Length: 1954, dtype: int64
```

Can you please assist/orient/help me in creating a dataframe that has the week (index) as columns?
That way I can have a table that looks like this

```
        0   1   2   3 ... 53

SanDOW  
SanPCF
SanXXX
.
.
.
```

And the appropriate values for each city by week?

Apologies in advance if I'm not following proper etiquette when asking this question.

Comment: I think you demonstrated SO "etiquette" perfectly.

Comment: The question is nicely written, but it might help to edit the question title to be more specific about your question, both to help get knowledgable people interested in answering it and to help people who are searching for this specific issue in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @mwaskom. I tried to improve the title based on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your two first columns form a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex), you can simply use [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
x.unstack(level=0)
```

to push the first index level to be a column.